# How to process soap data in rails app？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap

I wanna process soap data in my rails app, requirements is like this: 3rd party app connect to my app and post the soap data using http protocol, then in my controller, my app has to parse these soap data, store them and then send the result to the requestor using soap format. Now the problem is I do not know how to deal these in my controller. Which gem shoud I used? wash_out or sovan?? Could someone give a detail example？ Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of using SOAP, but there are a lot of documentation on internet, like [this](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-use-Savon-in-Ruby-on-Rails-Application-2367.php)

Basically you need to include the next code in your model

```ruby
def initialize(zip)
    client = Savon::Client.new("http://theserver.com?WSDL")
    response = client.request :web, :info, body:{"foo" => foo}
    if response.success?
        #do code
    end
end
```

This [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon) haves a good explanation too.

Comment: Thanks, but I've checked savon and it seems not met my requirement.